# Performance issue in mui drawer

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui

```
'use client'
import { Icon } from "@/presentation/components/shared";
import { SidebarItem, SidebarItemChild } from "@/presentation/interfaces/sidebars/drawer-items";
import { SidebarlistComponentProps } from "@/presentation/interfaces/sidebars/sidebar-list";
import { Collapse, List, ListItem, ListItemButton, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from "@mui/material";
import { useTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React, { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import SubItems from "../sidebar-items/subitems";


const SidebarItemComponent: FC<SidebarlistComponentProps> = ({ item, currentRoute, open, openItems, params, setOpenItems, i }) => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const router = useRouter();
  const [parentCollapsed, setParentCollapsed] = useState(false);

  const handleItemClickInternal = () => {
    const hasChildren = item.children && item.children.length > 0;
    const isOpen = openItems.includes(item.title);
    const areChildSubItemsOpen = item.children?.some((child) => openItems.includes(child.title)) ?? false;

    if (hasChildren) {
      setParentCollapsed(isOpen || areChildSubItemsOpen);
      setOpenItems(isOpen && !areChildSubItemsOpen ? openItems.filter((title) => title !== item.title) : [...openItems, item.title]);
    }
    item.route && router.push(`/${item.route}`);
  };

  const handleChildRouteClick = (child: SidebarItemChild) => {
    router.push(`/${child.route}`);
  };

  const selected = (item: SidebarItem | SidebarItemChild): boolean => {
    if (item.route) {
      return currentRoute ? currentRoute.includes(item.route) : false; // Active when currentRoute includes item.route
    }
    if ("children" in item) {
      return item.children?.some((child: SidebarItemChild) => selected(child)) ?? false; // Active if any child is selected
    }
    return false; // Default case: No child is selected, not active

  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment key={item.title}>
      <ListItem disablePadding sx={{ display: "block" }}>
        <ListItemButton
          selected={(parentCollapsed && selected(item)) || (!item.children && selected(item))}
          role={params === item.route ? "active-item" : undefined}
          onClick={handleItemClickInternal}
          sx={{
            minHeight: 48,
            justifyContent: open ? "initial" : "center",
            px: 2.5,
            "&.Mui-selected": {
              backgroundColor: "transparent",
              color: theme.palette.primary.light,
            },
          }}
        >
          <ListItemIcon
            sx={{
              minWidth: 0,
              mr: open ? 3 : "auto",
              justifyContent: "center",
            }}
          >
            <Icon
              iconName={item.icon}
              color={(parentCollapsed && selected(item)) || (!item.children && selected(item)) ? theme.palette.primary.light : ""}
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={item.title} sx={{ opacity: open ? 1 : 0 }} />
          {item.children &&
            item.children.length > 0 &&
            open &&
            (openItems.includes(item.title) ? <Icon iconName="icon-chevron-down-outline" /> : <Icon iconName="icon-chevron-left-box-outline" />)}
        </ListItemButton>
      </ListItem>
      {item.children && item.children.length > 0 && (
        <SubItems openItems={openItems} item={item} currentRoute={currentRoute} handleChildRouteClick={handleChildRouteClick} selected={selected} />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
export default SidebarItemComponent;
```

This is my code,selected function has the responsibility for returning booelan to either set active class or not

The peoblem is i think there's too much maping and looping,on every click so many loops starts to run, do you think it is bad for performance? What's my alternative

This is my code,selected function has the responsibility for returning booelan to either set active class or not

The peoblem is i think there's too much maping and looping,on every click so many loops starts to run, do you think it is bad for performance? What's my alternative

Answer (score 0):

Loops by default are linear in performance meaning the more data it has to loop through the more time it takes for it to run, see here for additional information on Big O Notation [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-big-o-notation#o-n)

Unless you are looping through a massive data set it really shouldn't be an issue. If you would like to test it, you can try to run a development environment see how that performs.